# Help identify a list of pitfalls in restructuring my country's roads

Tags: technology, technological-development, civilization, worldbuilding-process, construction

Help identify pitfalls in restructuring my country's roads.

**When I become King of a country, part of my reconstruction would be roads.**
Would you help identify a list of some of the major stumble blocks that would prevent this goal from realizing?
I am especially looking for a conceptual fail

The basic concept would be flow of traffic and the design would be based on a grid type of style, probably hexagon to keep roads as straight as possible over long distances but enable a more natural flow and interconnecting pattern.
The grid would most probably prevent most accidents based on the fact that a straight piece of road is safer than one with many bends and turns.
It would also be easier for future expansions of other interconnecting roads.
Roads would be kept as flat as possible and tunnels would be dug through mountains and large hills.

### The setting:

- I am a King of an African or similar country
- Government is optimized and highly effective
- Corruption is eliminated and government is earning their money
- Tax is high, but acceptable to people
- Special initiatives and returns is used to uplift people's spirits
- Education is free and different initiatives exists to create a country with highly intelligent people
- Everything else is like it is today

### Scope of changes:

- Make all roads form an interconnecting hexagon grid
- A road for civilian use consisting of 3 lanes or more
- A road for business use consisting of 3 lanes or more
- A road for emergency use consisting of 2 lanes
- Re-divide the land up to accommodate for the road changes (Land owners would get the same portion back, but it would now be a perfect square piece of land)
- Split the roads to separate traffic from oncoming traffic
- Automated smart road, traffic and offence management and vehicle control system - All vehicles will have an identification active tag that identify the vehicle type and owner details and offences.
- Have dedicated emergency roads, non-authorized vehicles would not be able to go onto these roads without clearance on the tags
- Real-time collision detection installed on all vehicles to prevent collisions and accidents
- Safe zones and rest areas
- Up speed limits in certain areas so that people can drive faster if the monitored vehicles are safe to do so

### Unrealistic events

Also unrealistic events is not plausible for preventing the goals from being reached, this includes but are not limited to:

- Interference from aliens
- The sun that explodes or any other event or occurrence outside of the atmosphere - Any large scale or small scale natural disaster
- Me dying before the goal is accomplished
- World apocalypse
- Some sort of large scale technology fail

### The list so far

The following are identified stumble blocks that will definitely not prevent this goal from being reached and are not considered as major stumble blocks:

- Money
- Time
- Resources
- People uprising
- Other countries interfering
- Project management
- Inefficiency
- Non-existing technology

Comment: Who will pay for all of this? Also, if there is currently a road with 3 lanes on each side and you proceed to reserve one for emergency traffic and one for commercial, you reduce the capacity for the majority of traffic by 67%. Welcome to traffic jam Hell.

Comment: All corruption will be eliminated, government will be streamlined with a few very competent action oriented people who would drive his/her responsibilities very effectively. Some of the tax money will be redirected to do this phase of the country's restructuring. Other money will be sourced from other countries by various initiatives well thought out by deep thinkers who would devise plans to within the law create schemes to gain the money, is it by marketing or hiring people to other countries or selling resources or winning money at sport ( a new system for instance).

Comment: A 3 lane road for cicilians only, seperate roads for emergency vehicles (maybe 2 lanes) and seperate roads for business use (maybe 3 lanes as well).

Comment: Another aspect that's unclear. Suppose you select a grid according to compass directions and you reach a town whose streets are at a 45 degree angle... do you tear down the whole town?

Comment: A good question that is. I haven't thought that out yet, but I suppose a possible solution would be to draw a square around the town which is square to the roads outside the town. Inside this square the roads will bend to connect to the town roads. Maybe a border between two squares in which traffic would be a bit slower but redirected towards the correct road.

Comment: I think your question is very broad, and with the information you give i doubt it is possible to provide an answer that is not purely opinion-based.
May i suggest you take a look at the [tour] and at the [help] center, and then maybe re-phrase your question?

Comment: To make the question less broad, I changed the question slightly.

Comment: Squares are rather inefficient and unnatural. Try [hexagons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexagonal_tiling) or other approximations of circles.

Comment: Giving it thought, hexagons would be a better design. I will adopt hexagons. Edited to add hexagons instead of squares.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(While I was typing this answer, you rewrote the question.)

From your question I infer that you are an Infrastructure Planning A.I. that has become self-aware and taken over the state of Kansas, declaring it the kingdom of Gridia. If so, congratulations, I applaud your achievement and will try to advise.

As a flat, mostly featureless land with rectangular borders and a relatively small number of towns and cities, former Kansas offers an excellent basis for you plan.
The meager tax income is a concern, but you have that covered per your comment. I expect Nigerian princes to be displaced from the internet by Kansas Businessmen "looking to move their capital abroad".

As you can write the law and direct funding, I expect that a smart road system can be developed and all vehicles equipped with transponders in a time frame of 5 years. You should reconstruct the most vital highway according to your preferred layout as a test case for the rest of the country.

Another 10-15 years should suffice to reconstruct all other roads. Due to the increased number of roads as well as increased total length and width, your total road surface area will probably increase by 400-500%. You will need to invoke Eminent Domain and reclaim all this land from its current owners. Please note that gun ownership is common in your new country and your eviction crews will need to be well-protected, or the work will fall behind schedule.

If my assumptions are wrong and you are not an A.I. or in control of former Kansas, please consider the enormity of what you are planning:

- The previously mentioned estimate of 400-500% more surface means you will spend large amounts of money buying land and concrete or asphalt.
- Most land is covered with hills, mountains, rivers and other natural features. Building bridges and tunnels to keep your roads straight will be impossible to finance. Going around such features using straight roads and 90 degree intersections will greatly increase the total road length as well as travel time as much as 40% (road was diagonal) to 100% (road goes around mountain).
- You would spend large amounts of money creating emergency roads that are never used (as crashes will be rare with automated traffic), it would probably be cheaper to employ large helicopter cranes to remove any broken-down vehicles.
- There is no reason to separate commercial and private traffic on roads that have more than enough capacity for 90% of the day. Consider instead flow control at highway entries, with normal and premium queues.

Finally, pretty much all existing roads have been built in their location exactly because they offered the best travel time at still affordable prices. Curved roads and angled intersections are not problems for either manual or automated traffic, so there is no reason to change intersections either.

### Summary

A rectangular grid is just not going to improve transport. Smart roads will, but they again remove the need for separated roads for different kinds of traffic.

Comment: Based on the previous question, I accept this answer. Well said and well done, I enjoyed your response. I would like you to answer the edited question as well if you have the time.

Comment: Thanks!. If you can elaborate on what you want to achieve with the road grid, I will try to point out any conceptual flaws. I went with the whole A.I. angle exactly because I wasn't able to figure out *why* you want that grid.

Comment: Okay, I edited it to include a small section on why the grid style, hope this is sufficient. Let me know if not. I am coming one step closer to world domination where I dominate a highly effective world and all the people loving me for what I have done for them hehehe.